# Why is the Belarus plane grounding incident treated more harshly than a similar one caused by the USA?

Tags: united-states, european-union, international-relations, belarus

[EU is punishing Belarus](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/eu-reaches-deal-belarus-economic-sanctions-according-austria-diplomats-2021-06-18/) with economic sanctions for grounding a plane to arrest a journalist, as well as blacklisting certain individuals from entering its territory and freezing their assets.

Why is this incident being treated much more harshly than when the USA attempted to ground a plane allegedly with Edward Snowden on board?

I would expect the [Evo Morales incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evo_Morales_grounding_incident) to be treated much more seriously, because it was a presidential flight, which should enjoy immunity, as opposed to grounding a plane with civilians, which damnable as it is, is not as diplomatically damaging.

Comment: Welcome to Politics SE!  Some may see this question as an attempt to discredit these sanctions, and attempts to promote/discredit political arguments is generally off-topic here.  While I will hold off on casting a close vote for now, I'm going to suggest that you choose one of these two events, ask specifically about that, and make no reference to the other, so that it comes across more as a genuine learning attempt.

Comment: "being treated" by whom?  Surely it is not surprising that Italy is not treating France "harshly" because Italy was one of the countries that closed its airspace. It's not surprising that Germany is not treating its close allies France and Italy harshly because "close allies"  It's not surprising that Russia and Bolivia were both pretty upset with this incident. Far more upset than they are with Belarus.

Comment: @JoeC Any political question may be seen by someone as an attempt do discredit something.

Comment: @JamesK specifically what I want to understand is why the United States were not sanctioned for this attempt

Comment: There is really no comparison between (1) denying a plane access to a nation's sovereign airspace, and (2) using military jets to force a plane to land within a nation's sovereign territory. The first is right laid out in international conventions and treaties since the beginnings of commercial air travel; the second is a violation of those conventions and treaties, equivalent to hijacking.

Comment: @JamesK that would make a pretty good answer

Comment: @RuslanOblov The USA was not directly involved.  The flight did not approach US airspace.  The US military (which does of course have a presence among the NATO allies) was not involved.  Perhaps the USA put a phonecall through to Italy and France to say "It would be great if..."  It is all rather speculative.  Similarly Russia is not directly involved in the Belarus forced landing.  And so the sanctions have been against Belarus instead of Russia. Why didn't Russia impose sanctions on France and Italy? Probably such sanctions would have hurt Russia more than France.

Comment: Why do you say presidential flights enjoy immunity? As far as I can tell, flights by heads of state have no such protection while civilian airliners are afforded a lot of protection under the [1944 Chicago convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Convention_on_International_Civil_Aviation).

Comment: @JJJ They seem to enjoy immunity from being *searched*, according the [then] Austrian president anyway. But that's not the same as being able to fly anywhere with anyone on board.

Comment: @Fizz Diplomatic immunity per the Vienna Convention is based on mutual consent, I don't think that applies when someone (who isn't already covered by the Convention) is merely flying over or when one lands in a foreign country. I'll ask it as a different question, it's actually quite interesting.

Comment: Rather than [cry that you're being oppressed](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/help-i-am-being-oppressed-why-do-people-keep-downvoting-my-opinions), you'd could actually work on improving the Q, because it's somewhere between unclear and silly. As it was pointed out by others: "treated more harshly" by whom? Do you expect the EU to sanction itself for the Morales thing? Did Russia sanction itself for Bucha? Do you expect the EU to sanction the US for the Morales thing?

Comment: For the latter, even if the US did something wrong (which is rather hard to prove in the Morales case with anything public) see https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74841/why-does-the-eu-have-a-huge-amount-of-sanctions-on-russia-but-not-on-the-usa for generic answers.

Comment: @Fizz that's all in your head and this question was asked more than a year ago. Rent free

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- The Snowden case involved the aircraft of the Bolivian president.
  The Protasevich case involved a commercial airliner.
  There seems to be some ambiguity just how much ICAO rules apply to government aircraft.
- The Bolivian government was *denied overflight* by several countries and thus found no other option but to request landing permission when fuel ran low.
  The Ryanair airliner had almost almost completely passed through Belarus airspace and was then *forced back*.
- France, Spain, Portugal and Italy refused an overflight permission.
  Belarussian authorities invented a bomb threat, yet did not permit the aircraft to land at the nearest airport.

If you look for a comparison, it might be better to look at [EgyptAir 2843](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achille_Lauro_hijacking#Interception_of_EgyptAir_jet) in 1985.

Comment: Frankly it's not even clear the fuel on the Bolivian plane ran low. They had enough to reach some Spanish islands in the Atlantic on their initial plan. When they landed in Austria, they claimed some issue with the fuel *gauge*, which magically repaired itself once on the ground. The whole thing was more like so Morales could claim he was "kidnapped" by Europeans. And the only country that actually refused overflight (and apologized for that later) was France.

Comment: @Fizz, I don't know how long they circled, sorting things out.

Comment: [Not much](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2013/07/tale-re-routed-bolivian-presidents-plane-falling-apart/313528/): "According to records of the plane's flight path, it travelled from Russia into Belarus, then over Poland and the Czech Republic until it entered Austrian airspace. Midway over Austria, the plane turned west, then doubled back before landing. [...] If it was rerouted from its original path, that only occurred once the plane was in Austria." There was link to the flight path in article but it's not working for me anymore.

Comment: Also, the claim that the plane was searched was also somewhat contradicted in later reporting. https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-security-snowden-austria-idUSBRE96605K20130707 "“Someone from the airport staff sought out the aircraft or the pilot after landing to inquire about the nature of the technical problem,” Fischer was quoted as saying.

“The Austrian official was advised that the defect was already fixed, and saw on this occasion that the plane was empty ... He did not look under the seats. There was no formal inspection, but no other people were found on board,” Fischer added."

Comment: The flight path can be found on this google link from a NYT article https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic01.nyt.com%2Fimages%2F2013%2F07%2F04%2Fworld%2F04snowden-map%2F04snowden-map-jumbo.png%3Fquality%3D75%26auto%3Dwebp%26disable%3Dupscale&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2013%2F07%2F04%2Fworld%2Fsnowden.html&tbnid=EyDBXfZH8F7VZM&vet=12ahUKEwi33cnPsabxAhWNwOAKHarzDVMQMygDegQIARBc..i&docid=PMl5DYiWOgD2UM&w=450&h=256&q=morales%20plane%20flight%20path&ved=2ahUKEwi33cnPsabxAhWNwOAKHarzDVMQMygDegQIARBc

Comment: @Fizz, you seem to see even fewer parallels than I do. How about writing that up as an answer?

Comment: *'There seems to be some ambiguity just how much ICAO rules apply to government aircraft.'* Is that so? Article 3 of [the Chicago Convention](https://www.icao.int/publications/documents/7300_orig.pdf) draws a clear distinction between civil and state aircraft? Are there other conventions that apply to state aircraft?

Comment: @JJJ, I was being vague because I'm no aviation expert, but from news reports there *mostly* seems to be an international understanding to extend the same courtesy to state aircraft. And breaking this in the Morales case was considered undiplomatic.

Comment: @o.m. yea I'm no expert either. I made it into a [separate question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/65891) to find out what exactly that *'international understanding'* is. It would make sense for there to be some agreement but it's odd that it's never referred to when these cases are reported on.